# Split Sample for EFA and CFA with Smaller Dataset

Tags: sample-size, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I have a dataset (n=290) that I need to run an EFA. I was hoping to also run a CFA but I'm unsure if I have enough data to do a split sample approach. Please advise.

Comment: I wouldn't split with that sample size.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Would you just run an EFA then and not the CFA at this time? I have 20 variables.

Comment: CFA adds information so I would do it. But interpret with caution.